# How is a column from a CSV file with JSON values parsed by Snowflake's COPY command?

Tags: json, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Recently, I generated a CSV file where one of its columns has JSON data. Since this is data I need to import to Snowflake, I'm using the `COPY` command to load the CSV into a table I created specifically for this purpose.

After reading the docs, I explicitly created a column, `json_data`, with a `VARIANT` data type. From my understanding of the docs, to load JSON data into a table, you need to (a) have a column with a `VARIANT` data type, and (b) load the data as a string (`VARCHAR`) and then parse into JSON using `PARSE_JSON`. [Here](https://docs.snowflake.com/user-guide/querying-semistructured#sample-data-used-in-examples) is an example of sample JSON data loaded manually into a table, and [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-load-json-values-in-a-csv-file) is a solution on how to load data from a CSV into a table using the COPY command. In this solution, they propose using a temp table where (I assume) JSON data is first loaded as a `VARCHAR` and then parsed to JSON from the temp table to the target table. In both solutions, the column with the JSON data is explicitly parsed using `PARSE_JSON` so that it can be loaded into the `VARIANT` column.

While trying things out, I was able to load the CSV into the table *without* using `PARSE_JSON`, with something plain and simple as

```
copy into mytable
from s3://...;
```

When I access the table, the JSON values had been adequately parsed into `OBJECT` data types and I can access their data hierarchically, as expected.

My question: How did this work? My expectation while trying that out was to get an error saying that a `VARCHAR` was provided and that a `VARIANT` was expected. This is what you would get if you use `INSERT` to add a JSON value into a `VARIANT` column without `PARSE_JSON`. Is there some heuristic process in the `COPY` command for fields that are meant to be loaded to VARIANT columns?